# Displaying Game Center modal view in landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, modalviewcontroller, game-center

I am using cocos2d engine in landscape-only orientation with no autorotation.

I want to display standart GC achievements modal view.
It's showing up normally, from bottom of screen (while holding device in landscape), but it is dismissing to the right side of the screen (like portrait modal views). It's seems to be changing orientation for dismiss animation, but view is not rotating before this. It's just sliding to the right.

Also I get a warning in console:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x41b9a0>.
```

That's how I showing this controller:

```
-(void)showAchievements:(id) sender {

    utilityController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:utilityController.view]; 

    GKAchievementViewController *achievements = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];
    if (achievements != nil)
    {
        achievements.achievementDelegate = self;
        [utilityController presentModalViewController: achievements animated: YES];
    }
    [achievements release];
}

- (void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{
    [utilityController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [utilityController release];
}
```

In gameConfig.h I have following configuration:

```
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone
```

Tried to change this to `kGameAutorotationCCDirector` - same thing. `kGameAutorotationUIViewController` - uiviews are jumping all over the screen.

Please do not suggest rotating UIView with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` - it's just a hack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) I solved this for all orientations with a [category for the GKMatchmakerViewController](https://github.com/kobold2d/Kobold2D/blob/master/Kobold2D/__Kobold2D__/kobold2d/KKGameKitHelper.m#L747). You can make the same category for the other Game Center view controllers.

This will force the GC views to use the current device orientation:

```
@implementation GKMatchmakerViewController (OrientationFix)
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // [RootViewController option removed for clarity]

    // all other autorotation types use the current device orientation
    ccDeviceOrientation orientation = [CCDirector sharedDirector].deviceOrientation;
    switch (interfaceOrientation)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            return (orientation == kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            return (orientation == kCCDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            return (orientation == kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            return (orientation == kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return NO;
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this orientation fix does not work for GKAchievementViewController for me. This view still slides up form the bottom when launching and after dismissing it - goes to the right side of the screen.

Comment: As a reminder, this exapmle code is for GKMatchmakerViewController. Are you sure you modified it for GKAchievementViewController?

Comment: Yes, of course.. Left it working this way for this time. Will investigate later.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first ever answer on Stackoverflow, so please forgive me if any formatting may not work.

Anyway, on to the code. This solution works for me, for the Achievements-Viewcontroller. Any other GK-Viewcontroller may work accordingly...

```
@implementation GKAchievementViewController (OrientationFix)

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

@end


@interface GKLeaderboardViewController (OrientationFix)

@end


-(void)showAchievements
{
    GKAchievementViewController *achievements = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];

    if (achievements != nil)
    {
        achievements.achievementDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController: achievements animated: YES];
    }

    [achievements release]; 
}

- (void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish: (GKAchievementViewController *)viewController 
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate; 
    [delegate.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
     self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Before presenting the ViewController